# Calculate size of UILabel with different font types

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont, cgrect, cgsize

I'm building an app with minimum version of iOS 7. In the method where i draw my cells, i have this code to draw a `UILabel` with different `UIFonts` types.

```
//Get Strings
NSString* author = [self getUserCreatedVideo:notf];
NSString* caption = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", [notf objectForKey:@"title"]];
NSString* challenge = @"challenged you to reply to";
NSString* timeToReply = @"24h to reply";
NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", author, challenge, caption, timeToReply];

NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myString];
UIColor* greenColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0 green:204.0/255.0 blue:153.0/255.0 alpha:1];

//Author
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor darkGrayColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,author.length)];
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0] range:NSMakeRange(0,author.length)];
//Challenge
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor lightGrayColor] range:NSMakeRange(author.length+1,challenge.length)];
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0] range:NSMakeRange(author.length+1,challenge.length)];
//Caption
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor darkGrayColor] range:NSMakeRange(author.length+1+challenge.length+1,caption.length)];
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0] range:NSMakeRange(author.length+1+challenge.length+1,caption.length)];
//Time To Reply
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:greenColor range:NSMakeRange(author.length+1+challenge.length+1+caption.length+1,timeToReply.length)];
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0] range:NSMakeRange(author.length+1+challenge.length+1+caption.length+1,4)];

cell.subtext.attributedText = str;
```

Now i want to calculate the `UILabel` text size, so that i can draw a `UILabel` 20px below `cell.subtext`. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to calculate height of text when you know text width.

```
CGRect rect = [str boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(cellWidth, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
```

Use resulting rect.size the way you want.

Comment: Yes, this is what i want. My lack of knowledge made me ask this.